# Tomorrow in NSDateComponents isolate day

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to retrieve tomorrows date based on the current date.  I get the correct string, but how do I isolate the day?

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:1];
NSDate *tommorrow = [cal dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date]  options:0];
[comps release];

NSLog(@"%@", tommorrow);
```

Returns a string of: `2011-10-01 15:07:07 +0000`

Comment: Please add more `tags` while you post the question. That will let others identify the question quickly. I think that is the reason you got the answer 25 minutes after you have posted the question. Otherwise you would have got your answer from others in a minute after posting the question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the *day* like this,

```
NSDateComponents *dcs = [cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:tomorrow];
int day = [dcs day];
```